# karma test for Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, karma-webpack

I have to test a function in my vue component - in depends on who click on the row in the table, the row should be repainted to other colors with vue bootstrap classes.

```
   setTransactionsSigns() {
    if (this.user.payload.isAdmin) {
      _.each(this.transactions, (transaction) => {
        transaction.signers = transaction.signers || [];

        let countSigners = transaction.signers.filter(s => 
        s.signed).length;
        let countAdmins = transaction.signers.length;
        if (countAdmins >= 1 && countAdmins === countSigners) {
          transaction._rowVariant = 'success';
        } else if (countAdmins >= 1 && countSigners >= 1 && 
          countAdmins > countSigners) {
          transaction._rowVariant = 'warning';
        } else if (countSigners >= 1 && countAdmins < countSigners) {
          transaction._rowVariant = 'info';
        } else {
          transaction.canEdit = true;
        }

        transaction.canEdit = countSigners <= 0;
      });
    }
  }
```

I wrote my first test with karma test framework:

```
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import Transactions from '@/components/Transactions';

  describe('Transactions.vue', () => {
  it('should get { countSigners: 2, countAdmins: 2 } and set color to 
  green', () => {
  const Constructor = Vue.extend(Transactions);
  const vm = new Constructor().$mount();
  const currentTransactionsSigns = { countSigners: 2, countAdmins: 2 
  };
  const setTransactionsSignsStub = 
  sinon.stub(currentTransactionsSigns.vm, 
  'setTransactionsSigns').returns('currentTransactionsSigns');
  const result = setTransactionsSignsStub;
  expect((result).to.be.true);
  expect(vm.$el.querySelector('.table-wrap').to.have.class('.table- 
  success'));
   });
 });
```

It seems it isn't working correctly.

```
Transactions.vue
    ✗ should get { countSigners: 2, countAdmins: 2 } and set color to green
        Trying to stub property 'setTransactionsSigns' of undefined
        throwOnFalsyObject@/opt/CopyDocuments/fork-fin/admin/node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js:3017:96
        stub@/opt/CopyDocuments/fork-fin/admin/node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js:2849:29
        webpack:///test/unit/specs/Transactions.spec.js:9:48 <- index.js:114772:46
```

I suppose the main problem with sinon.stub. It seems I'll try to transfer in it wrong data.

Comment: Yes, the problem is with sinon.stub. You declare currentTransactionsSigns as an object { countSigners: 2, countAdmins: 2  } which doesn't have a property called vm. You should use only vm instead because it is the viewmodel of your Transactions component.

Comment: Yes, I change it, but now I've got an undefined as the result                                                                        const setTransactionsSignsStub = sinon.stub(vm, 'setTransactionsSigns');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(setTransactionsSignsStub));

Comment: Yes because you should call the stubbed function. You just say const result = setTransactionsSignsStub and you don't call it.

Comment: Wait a moment. I thought I call it when I use stub. Ok, how can I call it?

Comment: No, with stubbing you just say: "I replace the original function with this: { return 'currentTransactionsSigns' }". You can call it with vm.setTransactionsSignsStub(). Take care that now you return the string 'currentTransactionsSigns' and not the value of the variable that you declared earlier.

Comment: My function doesn't return any data, so sinon.stub return undefined - and it's normal. I'll try to find another way to check how this method works properly or not.